# UDF to Coverting Date Format in Hive

Tags: hive

Hi all i am new to hadoop i need to create hive UDF to convert string datatype Date to date datatype i have one table where date datatype is string

```
abc 2/9/2017
xyz 2/8/2017
city 2/7/2017
state 2/1/2017
```

UDF will convert date into yyy-mm-dd and insert into another table where date column datatype is Date

```
output like

abc 2017/2/9
xyz 2017/2/8
city 2017/2/7
state 2017/2/1
```

i have tried with

```
TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date,'yyyy-mm-dd')))
```

but got NULL value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dd/MM/yyyy**

```
hive> select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('12/9/2017','dd/MM/yyyy')));
OK
_c0
2017-09-12
```

Comment: Hi Dudu thanks for the help but this is not working .when i am inserting that date into another table it has NULL value                                 My query:                                                                                          insert overwrite table table select Cust_name,TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(purchase_date,'dd-MM-yyyy'))) from old_table;

Comment: Take a look on my answer - I'm using a different format